# how to change calendar's size of JDateChooser

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I want change calendar's size to fit `JDateChooser` component's horizontal size

[image]

Help me~ here is my code

```
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateChooser.setBounds(329, 10, 171, 24);
dateChooser.getJCalendar().setBounds(352, 20,250, 80);          
panel.add(dateChooser);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: i have resized many times dateChooser size , but Calendar size is always same

Answer (score 1):

```
    dateChooser.getJCalendar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
```

RESULT

[image: JCalender OverSized]